# MySql Contar número de veces con una condición

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando mostrar la cantidad de equipos que trabajan por día haciendo viajes (un equipo puede realizar 1, 2, hasta 3 viajes en un día, y por cada viaje hecho se genera un registro con la observación 'Giro en Turno').

En base a esto, tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces para contar los equipos que trabajan en un día solo basta en la consulta un:

`SUM(IF(obs_reg_equipo = 'Giro en Turno', 0, 1)) as diasTrabajados`

Pero el problema con esto es que me cuenta también los otros giros si es que en ese mismo día el camión hace más de un giro.

En la tabla de ejemplo el resultado es 20, pero lo que espero es 18 (que son los id_equipo diferentes que trabajaron ese día).

¿Cómo quedaría la consulta en SQL para este caso ?

Gracias.

**EDITO**

La consulta que uso es esta

```
SELECT sum(if(re.obs_reg_equipo = 'Giro en Turno', 1, 0)) diasTrabajados
FROM registro_equipo re
WHERE re.fechaInicio_reg_equipo = '2018-08-13'
```

que me da de resultado los 20 registros con 'Giro en Turno'. Lo que espero es que el resultado sea 18, poniendo un filtro para que no se repitan los id_equipo iguales. La idea es que cuente el primero que encuentra y omitir los demas (DISTINCT id_equipo)

Disculpen la falta de información

Comment: Deberias agregar tu consulta completa.

Comment: `SUM(IF(obs_reg_equipo = 'Giro en Turno', 0, 1)) as diasTrabajados` no es la consulta completa. **[edit] la pregunta**. No termino de entender: `En la tabla de ejemplo el resultado es 20, pero lo que espero es 18 (que son los id_equipo diferentes que trabajaron ese dia)` = ¿cuál es entonces el id_equipo que debería traer correctamente? **[edit] la pregunta con los resultados esperados**

Comment: editado con la consulta que estaba empleando. Disculpen.

Comment: @AlejandroVega no hay problema y gracias por editar la pregunta. Es mas clara ahora con la información que proporcionas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que te estas complicando de mas.  Yo lo haria asi:

```
SELECT obs_reg_equipo, COUNT(DISTINCT id_equipo) AS diasTrabajados 
FROM registro_equipo re
WHERE re.fechaInicio_reg_equipo = '2018-08-13'
GROUP BY obs_reg_equipo
```

Comment: Esta respuesta responde mi pregunta. Gracias alanfcm. Consulta aparte, se puede hacer algo como un COUNT/IF en el SELECT ? pensando en generar más informes de otros estados, no solamente 'Giro en Turno'. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En ese caso talvez sea mejor un Group By.  Ya edite mi respuesta.